# why git unable to stage IDE's file?

Tags: git

Please look at the following image. Selected file unable to stage or commit.

[image]

This is IDE's self generated file.

i also tried via terminal but its not staging or commit even not adding in .gitignore .

any solution ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is listed as modified, then it has been committed before.

You could, from the terminal, do a:

```
git rm --cached .idea/workspace.xml
echo ".idea/workspace.xml" >> .gitignore
git status
```

That file shouldn't be listed as modified anymore.